# segmentation fault in my own STL Memory Allocator

Tags: c++11, memory-management, stl

I cannot list here an MCVE because its too long. I have an issue in my own written STL Memory Allocator but **only** when it is used in a **global** object [e.q. not in a function]:

```
class Heap
{
    static FaF::string heapString;
};

FaF::string Heap::heapString( "heapString" );
```

`FaF` is my `namespace` in which `string` is defined as follows:

```
namespace FaF
{
    using string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
}
```

`Allocator` is my STL Memory Allocator.

In the `Allocator` template I have this code:

```
T* allocate (std::size_t num, const void* hint = 0)
{
    T * allocatedPointer = static_cast<T*> ( getNextAvailableFreePointer( num ) );
    ...
```

The crash is in the function `getNextAvailableFreePointer` in this line:

```
mapForMemoryContainer.emplace( alignedMemorySize, MemoryContainer() );
```

`MemoryContainer` is just a very simple structure.

**My question:**

Why does the program crash when a **global** STL object is using my `Allocator`? I tested very sophisticated the `Allocator` class and it works properly [no memory leaks, ..] but under this one condition it crashes.

It crashes even before the 1st line of code in `main()`.

**Update:**

`mapForMemoryContainer` is a `std::map` defined in the base class:

```
class Allocator_Base
{
    public:
        Allocator_Base() { printf( "in Allocator_Base constructor\n" ); }

    protected:
        static std::map<int, MemoryContainer>   mapForMemoryContainer;
        ...
}
```

And the `Allocator` template is defined like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Allocator : public Allocator_Base
{
```

That's all. The text `in Allocator_Base constructor` is displayed twice before it crashes.

Comment: What is `mapForMemoryContainer ` ? Does that use your allocator as well ?

Comment: `It crashes even before the 1st line of code in main()` Do you have any static initialization ordering issues ? Will be needing some more context on the problem

Comment: I am pretty sure it's an issue with static initialization. My guess is that structure holding `mapForMemoryContainer ` has not been initialized. Pasting the stack trace of core dump would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, there isn't enough information here to do anything but guess. You really need to come up with a MCVE or just step through the code in a debugger. Try to make an MCVE; minimal doesn't necessary have to mean small, but I'm sure there are things you can strip out that don't affect the issue.

Comment: most probably it's the static initialization order fiasco. make a static variable with a constructor in your allocator, put a breakpoint on the constructor. is it called before the crash?

Comment: No, the valgrind dump doesn't help. The `Allocator_Base` constructor is not interesting. The constructor of `mapForMemoryContainer` is. Can you verify it was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize now all the comments in something like an answer but the answer belongs to the user `n.m.`:

1. It was a `static initialization order fiasco` (C) `n.m.`
2. I implemented his comment in this answer and moved all *sensible* objects into separate `get....()` functions.

Now it works like a charm.

Comment: The simplest and most reliable way is to move the static variable into a function. Use `static std::map<int, MemoryContainer>& getMemoryMap() { static std::map<int, MemoryContainer> memoryMap; return memoryMap; }`  This guarantees `memoryMap` initialisation before `getMemoryMap` returns for the first time.